# Find out if a selected item in ExtJs ina Ext.panel.tree has a child

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

does anyone know a way to find out, in ExtJS if a selected item in an `Ext.tree.Panel` has a child? I know you can find a selected item by doing `tree_dir.getSelectionModel().getSelection()` but I don't see any way to check if it has any children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance returned by `tree_dir.getSelectionModel().getSelection()` should have `hasChildNodes()` method specifically for that purpose.

Comment: To extend on this answer. A tree node is wrapped with [Ext.data.NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-hasChildNodes), which is where you will find `hasChildNodes()`.