# How to check the style properties in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How to check the style properties in extjs?

To set a style to a panel, we can use `setBodyStyle`. 
After setting the style, I want to check the value of a particular property.

Like,

```
var panel = Ext.getCmp('id');
if(panel.getStyles().fontSize == 24) //for example
    //do this stuff
else
    //do the other stuff
```

I am using extjs 4.1.1a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These methods are only available on Ext.dom.Element level. Meaning you will need to call

```
var panel = Ext.getCmp('id');
if(panel.el.isStyle('fontSize', 24)) //for example
    //do this stuff
else
    //do the other stuff
```

Please se the API for **[Ext.dom.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element)** (you may filter by 'style' for quick access)

Comment: Thanks this worked.. I got one last doubt(I think).. How to align the text inside the panel to middle?

Comment: Please come once on chat.. I have one doubt which I can't ask on SO. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23760/sencha

Comment: Sorry I didn't came on time by calling you.. please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/14772729/1577396